# how to restart this thread ? i dont want to create unnecessary threads just want to use single object of thread multiple times

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I want a function that can actually stop the thread and I can reuse its object

```
import threading as t
def print_s():
    print(s)
def thread_s(s):
    tt=t.Thread(target=print_s,args=(s))
    tt.start()
thread_s("hello")
thread_s("ok")
```

Comment: so why are you using threads?

Comment: i want to create a chat bot in which i want every thing to speak by machine side by side what it writes in chat box .thats why using thread but there are a no of chats with the user and i dont want to create every single chat object .@depperm

Comment: Not sure what your example code is supposed to illustrate.  Are you asking how to write a function that effectively does the same thing as `thread_s(...)` but without calling `Thread(...)` each time?  If so, then you probably want to use a _[thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool)_.  Unfortunately, I don't know enough Python to be able to recommend a thread pool implementation or, to tell you how to implement your own if that's what it takes.

Comment: thread pool is like a list of thread object?